# How to scrape html site for a specific div thats hard to find?

Tags: python

I want to extract the information from div which is inside a lot of other divs and other elements. I do not know how I get to the div with Beautifulsoup. Do I need to first search through the upper elements?

The type of code I used so far:

```
response = requests.get(html)
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")

div = soup.find("div",{"class":"mailobjectpanel_content")
```

I also tried to find all divs and then more specific ones within it but all I get is *None*. I simply do not know how to move inside so much html tags.

[html of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klOzA.png)

[hmtl of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMBbq.png)

[The last div is what I want to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ7r8.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Previously you had included images. Please do not include images. Include code blocks. That allows for one to test a possible solution.

Comment: you get None with  find_all? find_all("div",{"class":"mailobjectpanel_content") If so, the site may be dynamically loaded in which you need selenium or some other method to wait for the site to load, the scrape. what is the url? You really do need to provide a bit more to help you.

Comment: It is a website of web.de which is for emails. I want to make a programm that writes my emails...